# Encountering the error " '(' expected " when trying to execute a for loop to find 'sum of first ten numbers'

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a simple for loop program in PL SQL to find the sum of first ten numbers from 1 to 10 .

Earlier I had initialized the variable inside the declare . However , when I encountered the error , I declared it inside the declare part and initialized inside the begin part , hoping that that may have been the issue .
However I am still getting the error

```
SQL> declare
  2  sum integer;
  3  begin
  4  sum := 0;
  5  for k in 1..10
  6  loop
  7  dbms_output.put_line(sum+k);
  8  end loop;
  9  end;
 10  /



dbms_output.put_line(sum+k);
                        *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 25:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "+" when expecting one of the following:
(
```

Comment: sum is reserved keyword, try use other variable

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ thanks ! That worked .

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ `SUM` is actually not a reserved keyword, [see here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm).  But it looks like your suggestion resolved the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, its there

Comment: Yes, but _not_ under the reserved table, under the table following that.

Comment: well, sum() should be standard sql function

Comment: Notice that you're not computing the sum, but simply printing 1, 2, 3, … You could need something like  `vSum := vSum + k` and then print `vSum`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `SUM` is in the list of "PL/SQL Reserved Words" in the page you linked to.  Referencing it as `"SUM"` would fix the issue, but I would not recommend that!

Comment: @TonyAndrews No, it's not.

Comment: @tim Oh, yes it is!  row 1, column 4 under the text "PL/SQL Reserved Words (continued):"

Comment: I correct what I said.  `SUM` is not an Oracle reserved keyword, but it is a PL/SQL reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using oracle Oracle reserved words (like sum), please do not, but if you do use them then use them inside of the double quotes like this:

```
declare
    "sum" integer;
    begin
    "sum" := 0;
    for k in 1..10
    loop
    dbms_output.put_line("sum"+k);
    end loop;
end;
```

This will then be ok.
Hope this helps!